# Call a function in shared .so from C

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

My goal is creating a shared library created from c++. And I want to call a function in that library from a C program

I have a compareImage.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

EXTERNC int compareTwoImages();

#undef EXTERNC
```

and a compareImage.cpp file:

```
#include "SURF_Homography.h"
extern "C" int compareTwoImages(){
  ..
}
```

I have already created a shared library by using this command:

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -fpic -shared compareImage.cpp -o libcompareImage.so `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Then, I write a c program to call compareTwoImages() function from that shared lib like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   /* my first program in C */
   int test = compareTwoImages();
   printf("Comparison Results: %d\n", test);

   return 0;
}
```

and compile it with this command:

```
gcc -lcompareImage c_call_cpp.c -o callCpp.o
```

But it shows an error:

```
/tmp/cc0wuZTU.o: In function `main':
c_call_cpp.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `compareTwoImages'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that you are not linking your program with your shared library. Just because there's some file somewhere on your hard drive, with the function that your code uses, doesn't mean that the compiler will automatically know where it is. You have to explicitly link with that shared library (and make sure it's in the shared library search path, at runtime). See `ld(1)`'s documentation for the `-l` option, which you can pass via gcc.

Comment: For one, the library -lcompareImage should come after c_call_cpp.c.

Comment: Thanks Sam and Anon. My mistake is put -lcompareImage  before c_call_cpp.c, It works now.

Comment: @AnonMail: Answers in the answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with C++ or with your shared library or anything like that.

Narrow down your problem to a simple example next time.

Here you simply put the link flag in the wrong place:

```
gcc -lcompareImage c_call_cpp.c -o callCpp.o
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It needs to go *after* the object that'll use its symbols.

```
gcc c_call_cpp.c -o callCpp.o -lcompareImage
```

This is clearly stated in [the documentation for `-l`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘`foo.o -lz bar.o`’ searches library ‘`z`’ after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`. If `bar.o` refers to functions in ‘`z`’, those functions may not be loaded.